# php json_encode korean character broken. how to solve this?

Tags: php, json

In PHP `json_encode` Korean characters are broken. How it can be solved this?

I used `var_dump` but I need JSON type.

My web hosting has 5.2 PHP version, so I can't use

```
print(json_encode($json_output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));


while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $json_output[]=$row;
}

print(json_encode($json_output));
```

bellow is broken character

```
[
   {
      "name":"chulhoon",
      "description":"\ud558\ud558\ud638\ud638",
      "dob":"\uc548\ub155\ud558\uc138\uc694",
      "county":"\ub9cc\ub098\uc11c",
      "height":"\ubc18\uac00\uc6cc\uc694",
      "spouse":"\ubb50\ub4e4\ud558\uc138\uc694",
      "children":"\uc774\ubbf8\uc9c0\uc55e\uc790\ub9ac",
      "image":"http:\/\/microblogging.wingnity.com\/JSONParsingTutorial\/johnny.jpg"
   }
]
```

Comment: but value is different with in db,
how to solve this problem?
english is stored in db
i want print english that with json type

Comment: Alright... You should have phrased the question in these terms: I have English text but get Korean on return.

Comment: my web hosting is 5.2 php version, so can't use

Comment: @user3662974: Perhaps you should switch your hosting provider. PHP 5.2 is end of life for some years now. Even 5.3 is end of life since mid 2014.

Comment: haha sorry ^^
that's why if i change, i should clear all db data too.
web hosting company said.

Comment: May we know the expected values so we have a base to do some research?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function json_encode2($data) {
    switch (gettype($data)) {
        case 'boolean':
            return $data?'true':'false';
        case 'integer':
        case 'double':
            return $data;
        case 'string':
            return '"'.strtr($data, array('\\'=>'\\\\','"'=>'\\"')).'"';
        case 'array':
            $rel = false; // relative array?
            $key = array_keys($data);
            foreach ($key as $v) {
                if (!is_int($v)) {
                    $rel = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            $arr = array();
            foreach ($data as $k=>$v) {
                $arr[] = ($rel?'"'.strtr($k,array('\\'=>'\\\\','"'=>'\\"')).'":':'').json_encode2($v);             
        }

        return $rel?'{'.join(',', $arr).'}':'['.join(',', $arr).']';
    default:
        return '""';
}
```

}

this works cool!
thank you everybody.

echo json_encode2($data);

### json_encode2

{"test":"test data","sample":"sample string","data2":[0,1,2,3,{"beskin":"31"}],"bool":true,"number_data":33282,"pi":3.14}

Comment: How exactly did you reach the conclusion that built-in `json_encode()` is just broken and you need to roll your own? Wouldn't it be better to just fix the underlying bug rather than adding more layers of code you don't need in the first place?

Comment: sorry  Álvaro González
forgive me please.
My bad.

Comment: json_decode not working if above implemented. So better to use
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\- *]/', '', $subject);
. Ignore special characters and add only list of characters that are required to you.

Comment: Please use the solution below than this, it's much simpler.

Answer (score 4):

This is not broken. These strange sequences are unicode characters. You can try to use

```
print(json_encode($json_output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

instead, if you're PHP >= 5.4. That should keep unicode characters in their original form. But that could result in some other problems when storing or transferring the JSON string.

Comment: This must be the correct answer. I've used Google Translator and all Korean text make perfect sense: it's not misencoded English text! Also, how could `name` and `image` display fine otherwise?